# Google Maps - Infowindow won't display on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a Google Map with a KML file loaded.  I thought the infowindow would be something that would popup when a marker is clicked, but it's not popping up.  There are no errors in the console.

Thanks in advance, I'm sure I'm just missing something basic.  Also to be clear, I would like just the little popup box to appear above the pin, and not in a side window, etc.

Here's my Javascript for the map:

```
    var mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(38.662884,-121.4861797606); //Google map Coordinates

            var map;
            var kmlUrl = 'http://www.myurl.com/Earth.kml';


            map_initialize(); // initialize google map

            function map_initialize()

            {

                    var domMap = document.getElementById('google_map');

                    var googleMapOptions = 

                    { 

                        center: mapCenter, // map center

                        zoom: 11, //zoom level, 0 = earth view to higher value

                        maxZoom: 19,

                        minZoom: 1,

                        zoomControlOptions: {



                    },

                        scaleControl: true, // enable scale control

                        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // google map type

                    };



                    map = new google.maps.Map(domMap, googleMapOptions);            



                    var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

                    overlay.draw = function() {};

                    overlay.setMap(null);


            var kmlOptions = {

              suppressInfoWindows: false,

              preserveViewport: false,

              map: map

            };




            var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrl, kmlOptions);


            google.maps.event.addListener(kmlLayer, 'click', function(kmlEvent) {
            var text = kmlEvent.featureData.name;
            showInContentWindow(text);
            });

            function showInContentWindow(text) {
                var sidediv = document.getElementById('content-window');
            }
```

And here's a snippet of the KML:

```
 <Placemark>
    <name>ENGLE RD &amp; MIRADERA ST (EB)</name>
    <description>Buses head EB</description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-121.361321,38.632107</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
  <Placemark>
    <name>ENGLE RD &amp; MIRADERA ST (WB)</name>
    <description>Buses head WB</description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-121.360985,38.632031</coordinates>
    </Point>
  </Placemark>
```

Comment: I don't see any issues with infowindows with what code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i was able to get the functionality to work no problem on a test page, so there must be something in my production page that's causing the problem.  So I know my code is good, so I'll see what differences I can find.